# _SpinnerTextState#9863f(ticker active) was disposed with an active Ticker

Tags: flutter

I Have Try to run my Flutter app using SplashScreen but when I back to drawer of App When it gives the error like : **_SpinnerTextState#9863f(ticker active) was disposed with an active Ticker**
I Used animated_splash_screen package for splash screen. When I back to my drawer that time screen just give the black color within microsecond and console gives the error

```
import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'login/login.dart';
import 'pages/dashboard.dart';
import 'pages/drawer.dart';

 var username;
 Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 username = prefs.getString('username');
 runApp(
  MyApp(),
 );
 }

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
     home: MasterScreen(),
    );
  }
 }
   class MasterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  final AppBar appBar;
 const MasterScreen({Key key, this.appBar}) : super(key: key);
 @override
 _MasterScreenState createState() => _MasterScreenState();
 }

 class _MasterScreenState extends State<MasterScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;
  var _visible = true;
  @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 animationController = new AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: new Duration(seconds: 2),
);
 animation =
 new CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut);

 animation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));
 animationController.forward();

    setState(() {
       _visible = !_visible;
    });
    }
  @override
dispose() {
 animationController.dispose(); 
 super.dispose();
 }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  home:AnimatedSplashScreen(
    curve: Curves.bounceIn,
    splash: Image.asset(
      'assets/logo.png',
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ),
    nextScreen: username == null
        ? LoginScreen()
        : AppDrawer(
            child: DashBoard(
              appBar: widget.appBar,
            ),
          ),
    splashTransition: SplashTransition.scaleTransition,
    pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.leftToRightWithFade,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    animationDuration: Duration(
      seconds: 2,
    ),
  ),
);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can you share the full error log?

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana Sir The console shows only this error = _SpinnerTextState#14910(ticker active) was disposed with an active Ticker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above code AnimatedSplashScreen package is replace by simple SplashScreen package and we find the splash screen package here   [splash screen package here](https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen)

```
 SplashScreen(
    
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    seconds: 5,
    navigateAfterSeconds: LoginScreen(),
    image: new Image.asset(
      'assets/logo.png',
    ),
    styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
    photoSize: 150.0,
    loaderColor: Colors.white,
    loadingText: Text(
      'Welcome To QA Platform',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```